# Display Custom View in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I have an objective-c custom view, I marked it as IB_DESIGNABLE and I got error in the storyboard:

MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: dlopen(example.app, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    example.app: mach-o, but wrong architecture

and another one:

MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of CustomView: dlopen(example.app, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    example.app: mach-o, but wrong architecture

I am working on Xcode 6.1 beta. I tried to make a framework as described in the WWDC session 411, but I got same error.

any idea, what's missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Valid Architectures: arm64

you should add arm64 to Valid Architectures. Designables need it!

Comment: I actually have arm64 in my valid architectures but still have the issue. Do I need to set "Build Active Architecture Only" for debug as well, or does Xcode do a production build for designables automatically under the hood?

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert  yes, in order to fix this for me, I needed to set Build Active Archs Only to NO for debug as well.

Comment: @corichen It seems really weird to me that you would need the arm64 architecture for Interface Builder that runs on your computer's Intel processor... I believe that this is an Xcode bug.

Answer (score 2):

Adding arm64 to to Build settings->Architectures, cleaning and deleting derived data worked for me.